# ntheorem: Framing environment with vertical lines on both the left and right sides. Help with right side

Tags: ntheorem

When I write maths in LaTeX, I put it into a custom `ntheorem` environment called `outlined`, that gives it a grey line on the left. `outlined` is defined as:

```
\def\theoremframecommand{{}{\color{gray!50}\vrule width 5pt \hspace{5pt}}{}}
\newshadedtheorem{exa*}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{outlined}{
    \begin{exa*}
    }{
    \end{exa*}
}
```

Thus

```
Lorem ipsum
\begin{outlined}
...
\end{outlined}
Lorem ipsum
```

Produces
[image]

However, I would like to add a matching line on the right side of this environment (after the equation number). I have been unable to do this myself and Google doesn't seem to have an answer. Hope someone on here can help.

Comment: In my answer, Ihad forgotten to set the skips above and below the environment. I've updated the code (and the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `framed`, but it's easy with `mdframed`, which has an option ‘ntheorem’, so I propose this solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=5pt, linecolor=Gainsboro!75!Lavender, topline=false, bottomline=false, skipabove=15pt, skipbelow=20pt]{thm}{Theorem}
   \theoremclass{Theorem}


\begin{document} \textsc{Enqueue}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{thm}
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{e}^{\pi \mathrm{i}} + 1 = 0.
\end{equation}
\end{thm}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{191, 191, 191}
\newtcbtheorem{mytheo}{Theorem}%
              {enhanced jigsaw,% 
               sharp corners,%
               boxrule=0pt,%
               opacityfill=0,%
               fonttitle=\color{black}\bfseries,%
               borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{mylightgray},%
               borderline east={5pt}{0pt}{mylightgray}%
               }{th}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{mytheo}{}{}
\begin{equation}
e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There appears to be excess vertical aeparation between the theorem header and the equation.  (Compare with the answer by Bernard.)